# On Click fade-out and fade-in Animation Angular

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I implemented fade in fade out animation for a div element. what I want to do is something like this.

- when page initial renders there is div element displaying some
  number.the right and left side i have 
      two-buttons.
- When a user clicks on one of those buttons I want to remove the
  numbers in div element and add 
      display the newly created numbers in the div

my problem is when the user clicks on one of those button fade-out part of the animation working fade-in part is not working.

this is stackblitz 
[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ro6qhr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 5):

It is working as expected. You have two different states that are toggled when you click a button. In `initial` state, the opacity is 1 and the data is displayed. And in `final` state the opacity is 0. So the data isn't displayed until you switch to the `initial` state again.

To achieve your desired behavior, you could use only one state and use `:enter` and `:leave` transitions to toggle between the opacity. The following should do it.

Component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
   animations:[
    trigger('fade', [
      state('in', style({ opacity: 1 })),
      transition(':enter', [ style({ opacity: 0 }), animate(600) ]),
      transition(':leave', animate(600, style({ opacity: 0 })))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  array = [0, 10, 20, 30, 50]

  goToPrevSet(){
    this.array = this.array.map(data => data - 5)
  }

  goToNextSet(){
    this.array = this.array.map(data => data + 5)
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="main-container" style="display:inline-flex">
  <button style="padding:5px;font-size:17px;border: 1px solid #1eb2a6; background-color:#d4f8e8;border-radius:5px;cursor: pointer" (click)="goToPrevSet()">Prev</button>
  <div *ngFor="let item of array">
    <div style="padding:5px;" [@fade]="'in'">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
  <button style="padding:5px;font-size:17px;border: 1px solid #1eb2a6; background-color:#d4f8e8;border-radius:5px;cursor: pointer" (click)="goToNextSet()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euf9kx)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using following simple step No need to use a function to do a small work which is easily possible with just a 1 line css.

Remove all animation code and comment out changeAnimationState() calling from ts

```css
.animate-opacity{animation:opac 0.8s}@keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
```

```html
<div class="animate-opacity" style="padding:5px;">{{item}}</div>
```